# VBA Excel macro: use Range to act on a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am very much a beginner when it comes to VBA programming.

I have a Macro that hides or shows columns based on the value in one cell:

```
Sub HideColumnsMacro()
 Range("b8:o8").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
 v1 = Range("b2").Value + 1
 If v1 < 12 Then
  With Range("b8")
   Range(.Offset(0,v1), .Offset(0, 12)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End With
 End If
End Sub
```

I want to be able to get this same functionality when I change a cell on a different sheet.  Is there a way I can tell this Macro to act on this sheet, when it is run from a different one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your macro, specify the exact sheet:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b8:o8").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Qualify your `Range`s with the name of the worksheet:

```
Sheet1.Range("b8:o8").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Comment: +1 arbitrarily had to choose which of these correct answer to accept.

Comment: Actually its not clear from this answer that Sheet1 is a worksheet type variable that has already been referenced. Given that the OP indicates he is a VBA newbie.

Comment: @Anonymous It's not a variable, it's a sheet name. Each sheet has a name in VBA, and that name represents the sheet in code without any additional actions. Thomas uses a different, "user name", the one you change from the Excel interface, as opposed to "VBA name" which you change in the IDE. I agree his answer might be clearer for a newbie though.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right how stupid of me... sorry. Just trying to look at it from teh OP's POV.