# VBA Can't Loop Through All Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, and I got stuck with a simple problem. I want to select all cells with data in the worksheet, paste them by value, then replace "#NUM!" with ""(nothing) and repeat all the above steps in all worksheets. The issue is that it wouldn't loop through all worksheets. Please help.

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

'Select all, copy and paste-by-value
ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

'Find and Replace
Cells.Replace What:="#NUM!", Replacement:=""

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel macro: use Range to act on a different worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656443/vba-excel-macro-use-range-to-act-on-a-different-worksheet)

Comment: Sorry, but how's my post duplicate to that one? I checked out that post but I don't see a solution to my question.

Comment: Maybe he meant the missing `ws.` at the start of the line `Cells.Replace What:="#NUM!", Replacement:=""`?

Comment: As @Ralph says, you're missing the `ws.` before `Cells`. Voting to close the as being the result of a simple typographic error.

Comment: Ralph and Ken are right. Thanks for the help!