# Range of object failed

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to fill Color in a range of cells depending on multiple conditions  and selection of the cells. here is the code

```
Sub color()



  Dim j As Integer
  Dim testfallname As String
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim rCell As Range
  Dim UnionRange As Range
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("1-BR_Vorschlag")

  ws.Activate
  For j = 7 To 1000
If ws.Cells(1, j) = "ARB11" Or ws.Cells(1, j) = "FVB1" Or ws.Cells(1, j) = "FVB4E" Then
testfallname = Cells(5, j)
Set rng = ws.Range("G5:AQ5").Find(testfallname)
End If

   Set UnionRange = Union(ws.Range(Cells(34, rng.Column), ws.Range(Cells(39, rng.Column), ws.Range(Cells(49, rng.Column), Cells(50, rng.Column), ws.Range(Cells(53, rng.Column), Cells(54, rng.Column), ws.Range(Cells(59, rng.Column), Cells(61, rng.Column), ws.Range(Cells(66, rng.Column), Cells(77, rng.Column), ws.Range(Cells(85, rng.Column), Cells(97, rng.Column)))))))))


With ws
  For Each rCell In UnionRange
        If rCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            rCell.Interior.color = 8421504
       End If
    Next rCell
End With
Next j
```

Here is the Actual code. Now I get an error again saying wrong number of arguements or invalid property assignment. It Debugs the Union Range line. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel macro: use Range to act on a different worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656443/vba-excel-macro-use-range-to-act-on-a-different-worksheet)

Comment: As a side note, you don't need the `With`, and you should use conditional formatting to color cells based on values.

Comment: What line gives you the error? And I'm pretty sure you have to use `ColorIndex` instead of `Color`.

Comment: I get the error on the line Set UnionRange = Sheets("1-BR_Vorschlag").Union(Range(Cells(34, 7)),  Range(Cells(39, 7))).I have tried it on a blank sheet in a new work book with the same sheet Name too. It gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the target sheet in the wrong spot. You use it like this(these values are random for the sake of an example):

```
Set UnionRange = Union(sheets("1-BR_Vorschlag").Range(cells(3, 10), cells(8, 9)), sheets("1-BR_Vorschlag").Range(cells(13, 22), cells(28, 49)))
```

Basically just move the target inside union and it should work fine. I think it works this way so you can use union on ranges from different sheets at the same time.

Comment: Hi I just used your idea and I have some Thing like this  Set UnionRange = Union(ws.Range(Cells(50, 10), (Cells(60, 10)), ws.Range(Cells(75, 10), (Cells(90, 10)))))   and now it gives me wrong number of arguements or invalid property assignment.

Comment: You put a bracket infront of the "cells(60,10)" and didn't close it so it messed it up.

You actually don't need the extra brackets around the second "Cells" in the range, what I have below will work

`Set UnionRange = Union(ws.Range(cells(50, 10), cells(60, 10)), ws.Range(cells(75, 10), cells(90, 10)))`

If this works click the check mark!

Comment: I have the same Problem again. I have updated it in the question

Comment: You are missing brackets. 
It is supposed to be formatted like this:
`union(Range1,Range2...)`
and range is supposed to be formatted like this:
`target.range(cells1,cells2)`
So together it should be like this:
`union(range1(cells1,cells2),range2(cells3,cells4))`
you have it as `range(cells1,range(cells2,cells3))` which is incorrect syntax.

Comment: I have set it up according to the Syntax which you specified    Set UnionRange = Union(ws.Range(Cells(34, rng.Column), Cells(35, rng.Column), ws.Range(Cells(39, rng.Column), Cells(40, rng.Column)))) but I still get the same error.Please correct me if the Syntax is wrong

Comment: You missed the bracket closing the first range. Insert where I highlighted and remove one from the end. paste what I have below beneath the line of code you used and carefully look for where it was wrong

Set UnionRange = Union(ws.Range(cells(34, rng.Column), cells(35, rng.Column)`)`, ws.Range(cells(39, rng.Column), cells(40, rng.Column)))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` to select all the blank cells at once.

```
Sub color()

    Dim r As Range
    With Worksheets("1-BR_Vorschlag")
        Set r = Union(.Cells(34, 7), .Cells(39, 7), .Cells(49, 7), .Cells(50, 7), .Range(.Cells(53, 7), .Cells(54, 7)), .Range(.Cells(59, 7), .Cells(61, 7)), .Range(.Cells(66, 7), .Cells(77, 7)), .Range(.Cells(85, 7), .Cells(97, 7)))
        Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Interior.color = 8421504
    End With

End Sub
```

I found using the Union method a little tedious I prefer create a string and use the Range method.

```
Sub Color2()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Worksheets("1-BR_Vorschlag").Range("$G$34,$G$39,$G$49:$G$50,$G$53:$G$54,$G$59:$G$61,$G$66:$G$77,$G$85:$G$97")
    Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Interior.color = 8421504

End Sub
```