# IF/Then checking for any value in cell

Tags: vba

I've got a report that I have a macro set up to filter for some criteria.  If anything shows up in row 2, I want to have it set up to email me the results.  If there isn't anything in the report, a message box will suffice stating there are no results.

I have everything working except the beginning IF where if is checking to see if there is anything in A2.  I've tested multiple things and regardless of if there is or isn't data in A2, the macro is emailing me.

What I currently have setup:

```
If Range("A2").Value = "" Then    
    Emails me the results (working fine)    
Else
    MsgBox ("No BW Loan Payments") (also working fine in testing)    
End If
```

Any ideas, I'm struggling to find other ideas on Google.

Comment: Are you sure it's the [correct `Range("A2")`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2656443/11683) you're checking?

Comment: Assuming your active sheet **is** the one you are meant to be checking, then try putting a `MsgBox "|" & Range("A2").Value & "|"` straight after the `If` statement (in the part that emails you stuff) so that you can see what value it thinks is in A2.

Comment: Also, in your question you say "to filter for some criteria" - does that perhaps mean you want to check on the value in the cell in the second **visible** row in column A, rather than on cell A2?

Comment: Ignore my first comment - that `MsgBox` would only ever display `"||"` - I was reading the `If` statement as being `<> ""` instead of as `= ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your condition not setup incorrectly? You're asking it to email you every time there is no data in cell A2. Try this instead, using the `<>` operator.

```
If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then    
    Emails me the results (working fine)    
Else
    MsgBox ("No BW Loan Payments") (also working fine in testing)    
End If
```

Comment: The problem is not with A2, A2 will have data, it might be hidden with the filter.  The OP is assuming that when the filter is empty that that mean A2 is empty when in fact it is only hidden, unless of course the OP is using an advance filter into a new range.

Comment: Hi Scott, I take your point. But either way, checking A2 or Row 2 (visible), the IF statement construct is incorrect in OP post. OP said he doesnt want an email if A2/Row2 is blank. Perhaps I've interpreted it wrong?

Comment: I agree that the logic is backwards but there is more to this problem than that.

Comment: Sigh - I'm definitely getting old - I hadn't even noticed that that test is probably back-to-front ("probably", because it might be that the email should only be sent if it **is** blank) but, as Scott says, that doesn't explain why the email is **always** being sent when the cell that the OP thinks that the code is pointing to is blank or not blank.