# Combining R1C1 in vba with a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use a `vlookup` in `sheets("formula").range("D3")` and autofill it to all cells between D3 and the cell in the last row and last column in `sheets("formula")`. The lookup values are in `sheets("combined")` which has a dynamic range in terms of the number or rows. Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Vlookup ()
    Dim lastcol As Integer
    With Sheets("Formula")
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    Dim lastrow As Long
    With Sheets("Formula")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim comlast As Long
    With Sheets("Combined")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Sheets("Formula").Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3&"" | ""&R1C,Combined!R2C3:R" & comlast & "C4, 2, FALSE),"" "")"
    Sheets("Formula").Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Formula").Range("D2:D" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Sheets("Formula").Range("D2:D" & lastrow).AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Formula").Range(Cells(2, "D"), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

I'm getting a run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: In the third `With` block you are assinging `lastrow` instead of `comlast`.

Comment: Thank you! Failed to pick that up. I've corrected it and the same error is still coming up

Comment: Now you need to debug and inspect the three values at the point before assigning the formulas.

Comment: You also need to [qualify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2656443/11683) the nested `Cells(lastrow, lastcol)` with the sheet object.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: @Scott Craner: the last line before end sub

Comment: Then your answer is in the @gserg last comment. `...Sheets("Formula").Range(Sheets("Formula").Cells(2, "D"), Sheets("Formula").Cells(lastrow, lastcol))...`

Comment: Appreciate the help Scott and GSerg, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the following:

```
Dim comlast As Long
With Sheets("Combined")
    Comlast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

And

```
With Sheets("Formula")
    .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3&"" | ""&R1C,Combined!R2C3:R" & comlast & "C4, 2, FALSE),"" "")"
    .Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("D2:D" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .Range("D2:D" & lastrow).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

Comment: @Ian if that doesn’t work still, you may have to use .Range(Cells(last Row,last Col).Address) instead of .cells(last Row,last Col)

Comment: Got it to work after Scott and GSerg's help but I'll look up .address for future reference

Comment: @Ian no worries